# "RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-7, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, nodes, command-prompt

I am trying to configure a cluster environment for RabbitMQ on a single machine(Laptop). I am following this [TUTORIAL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) from RabbitMQ website. My machine is using **Windows 7** and **RabbitMQ server 3.3.0**. When I tried to run the following command:

```
RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672 RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit rabbitmq-server -detached
```

Following error occurs on command prompt:

```
"RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

What this command does is it is basically setting variables **RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT** and **RABBITMQ_NODENAME** for the server to run as a single node with name **rabbit** and on port **5672**. Similarly, I would try to start another node with the name **hare** and port **5673**. I know this a system path kind of issue, but still, I am unable to sort it out. Can somebody help me out!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after banging my head on the wall, I finally managed to create a cluster on single machine on **WINDOWS**. It looks easy in LINUX, but, for Windows you need to a bit of work. On the command prompt, execute the commands as described below. Here are the steps to achieve clustering on single machine using Windows with two nodes:

#### Step 1:

```
a) set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
b) set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=hare
c) set RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}] -rabbitmq_stomp tcp_listeners [61614]
```

#### Step 2:

Run the following command to create a node named "hare" in this case:

```
rabbitmq-server -detached
```

#### Step 3:

Now join the cluster by running following commands:

```
a) rabbitmqctl -n hare stop_app
b) rabbitmqctl -n hare join_cluster rabbit@hostname
c) rabbitmqctl -n hare start_app
```

You can also provide the necessary configurations in the **rabbitmq.config** file which you will have to create under the following directory:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
```

But, creating the file will persist the configurations and they will be automatically applied whenever RabbitMQ server starts.
That's it for creating a node and joining the cluster on single machine. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 3):

you have to set the environment variables using `set`

```
set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672
echo %RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT%
```

[image]

Comment: you provided really great knowledge that I was lacking. No doubt it is the base for the answer of my question. Thanks a lot!!